# android touch tracking

Tags: android

I have a Main activiy, and many other activity that extends main activity. I want to track all touch events like clicking button, listview item, textView..etc in child activities .But i was unable to do that.I Implemented onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) in main activity,

```
@Override
onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onTouchEvent pressed");
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

But This function was not called.. any ideas?

Comment: See, every activity has its own onTouchEvent listener, and you can listen to touches only in activity you're currently in.

Comment: Well, create a class which updates co-ordinates of a screen and save those data in variables to access whenever or wherever you want, BTW this is not reliable as you have to implement something like if touch was on (x,y) co-ordinates that means touch must be on specific button(Approximate)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Tapjacking/Jackalope/src/com/commonsware/android/tj/jackalope/Tapjacker.java.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Tapjacking/Jackalope/src/com/commonsware/android/tj/jackalope/Tapjacker.java)

It is a service that adds a transparent View to the window manager. The service also implements a onTouchListener. The listener will track all touch events while the app is running.

It is probably the easiest to implement and provides a central place to track touch events.